# Bourbon not finding font-face mixin (Rails 3.2.2)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, bourbon

Following [Ryan Bates' screencast on Bourbon](http://railscasts.com/episodes/330-better-sass-with-bourbon?view=comments), I have my `application.css.scss` file as such:

```
@import "bourbon";
@import "main";
@import "events";
..etc.
```

In my `main.css.scss` stylesheet everything works and I can use the `@include transition()` mixin perfectly, but when I try to use `@include font-face`, I get an `Undefined mixin 'font-face'.` error in my Rails app.

The exact line of code is

```
@include font-face(HN, '/helveticaneue', normal, $asset-pipeline: true);
```

I've tried without the `normal` and just `'helveticaneue'` (no slash). The file exists and isn't corrupt because using CSS `@font-face` works.

As per [this Bourbon issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/130) I have

```
gem 'bourbon', :git => 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon.git', :ref => 'f93cf9e'
```

in my Gemfile.

Why isn't Bourbon picking up the mixin?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem for me. If you include bourbon, all css files must be .scss oder .sass files or you will geht this unrelated error. If you have some css files, which are not scss or sass, you have to rename them in scss (or sass).